# Firefox: New tab doesn't execute JS and render dynamic content with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, browser, innerhtml

I have a site where all the template content, even static, is pre-compiled in JS functions and rendered to the page via innerHTML.  For some reason in Firefox(35.0.1) when I right click on a link on page1 and choose to open that link, page2, in a new tab(not window), teh page is blank as it only contains the page source from the server and does not execute the JS to render the markup.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Had initially replied and said an update fixed it.  It didn't.  Still occurs in FF(36.0.1).